# How to make scons make gcc with assembly file during compilation?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, compilation, scons

For example, I've got a 'b.c' file, I compile and generate the code, while I wish to see an intermediate assembly file, I can do under shell like this:

> gcc -S b.c
>   gcc -c b.c
>   gcc b.o -o b

My question is, how to specify inside scons SConstruct, with all these steps, to make sure I get b.s, b.o and 'b' executable? Seems scons only support functions like Program, Object, Library, so I only get b.o and 'b'. But how to make out 'b.s', while I don't wish to introduce any duplicated work by the compiler(to save time).

Thanks.

Comment: add `-save-temps` option to the command line

Comment: -save-temps works!

Comment: I had no doubts